# Approximate the relationship between 6 nonlinear functions involving elliptic integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, approximation

I am trying to solve a physics-related problem, which results in approximating a relationship between 6 symbolic functions $F_1(\alpha,\beta ,x_0,y_0),F_2(\alpha,\beta ,x_0,y_0),...,F_6(\alpha,\beta ,x_0,y_0)$. The functions contain elliptic integral and their denominators are identical. My goal is to remove the variables $\alpha,\beta ,x_0,y_0$, and try to approximate the  relationship with ideally a polynomial (example: $F_1^2 + F_2^2 + F_3^2 +F_4^2 + F_5^2 + F_6^2 = 1$), which can be used as a model to fit 6D data.

Following are two functions out of 6:

$F_1(\alpha,\beta ,x_0,y_0) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-c\sin(u)+c x_0\cos(u)\sin(u)-az_0 \cos(u)\sin(u)+c y_0\sin(u)^2-bz_0\sin(u)^2}{\sqrt{(bx_0-ay_0-b\cos(u)+a\sin(u))^2+(c+(-cx_0+az_0)\cos(u) + (-cy_0+bz_0)\sin(u))^2}}du\\
F_2(\alpha,\beta ,x_0,y_0) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{bx_0 - ay_0 - b\cos(u)+ a\sin(u)}{\sqrt{(bx_0-ay_0-b\cos(u)+a\sin(u))^2+(c+(-cx_0+az_0)\cos(u) + (-cy_0+bz_0)\sin(u))^2}}du\\
\text{ where } a=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta), b= \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta), c=\sin(\alpha), \alpha,\beta, x_0,y_0\in \mathbb{R}, z_0 =-\frac{y_0\sin(\beta) + x_0\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)}.$

Following is the code for the integrands of the six functions:

```
F1Integrand = (Sin[u]*(-c + (c*x0 - a*z0)*Cos[u] + (c*y0 - b*z0)*Sin[u]))/Sqrt[(b*x0 - a*y0 - b*Cos[u] + a*Sin[u])^2 + (c + ((-c)*x0 + a*z0)*Cos[u] + ((-c)*y0 + b*z0)*Sin[u])^2]
F2Integrand = (b*x0 - a*y0 - b*Cos[u] + a*Sin[u])/Sqrt[(b*x0 - a*y0 - b*Cos[u] + a*Sin[u])^2 + (c + ((-c)*x0 + a*z0)*Cos[u] + ((-c)*y0 + b*z0)*Sin[u])^2]
F3Integrand = -((Cos[u]*(-c + (c*x0 - a*z0)*Cos[u] + (c*y0 - b*z0)*Sin[u]))/Sqrt[(b*x0 - a*y0 - b*Cos[u] + a*Sin[u])^2 + (c + ((-c)*x0 + a*z0)*Cos[u] + ((-c)*y0 + b*z0)*Sin[u])^2])
F4Integrand = (Sin[u]*((-b)*x0 + a*y0 + b*Cos[u] - a*Sin[u]))/Sqrt[(b*x0 - a*y0 - b*Cos[u] + a*Sin[u])^2 + (c + ((-c)*x0 + a*z0)*Cos[u] + ((-c)*y0 + b*z0)*Sin[u])^2]
F5Integrand = -((Cos[u]*((-b)*x0 + a*y0 + b*Cos[u] - a*Sin[u]))/Sqrt[(b*x0 - a*y0 - b*Cos[u] + a*Sin[u])^2 + (c + ((-c)*x0 + a*z0)*Cos[u] + ((-c)*y0 + b*z0)*Sin[u])^2])
F6Integrand = (-c + (c*x0 - a*z0)*Cos[u] + (c*y0 - b*z0)*Sin[u])/Sqrt[(b*x0 - a*y0 - b*Cos[u] + a*Sin[u])^2 + (c + ((-c)*x0 + a*z0)*Cos[u] + ((-c)*y0 + b*z0)*Sin[u])^2]
a = Cos[alpha]*Cos[beta]
b = Cos[alpha]*Sin[beta]
c = Sin[alpha]
z0 = -(y0*Sin[alpha] + x0*Cos[alpha]*Sin[beta])/(Cos[alpha]*Cos[beta])
```

What I have tried so far, is to:

1. Solve the elliptic integral symbolically, then approximate the elliptic integrals.

   1) I used [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) and solved the elliptic integral based on [the paper from Calson](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771719990336X). The result involves all three kinds of incomplete elliptic integrals.

   2) I tried to approximate them based on Taylor expansion and Pade approximation as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350160/approximations-of-the-incomplete-elliptic-integral-of-the-second-kind). However, the approximation is only accurate around one point and the relationship differs a lot than the original ones.
2. I compute the lower bounds of $F_1,F_2,...F_6$, such that no elliptic integrals are involved.

   1) Use the inequality: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} \leq |a|+|b|+|c|$

   $F_{1\text{(lowerBound)}} =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-c\sin(u)+c x_0\cos(u)\sin(u)-az_0 \cos(u)\sin(u)+c y_0\sin(u)^2-bz_0\sin(u)^2}{|bx_0 - ay_0 - b\cos(u)+ a\sin(u)| + |c + (-cx_0 + az_0)\cos(u)+ (-cy_0 + b z_0)\sin(u)|}du$

   After tangent half-angle substituion with $t = \tan(\frac{u}{2}),\sin(u)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos(u)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$:

   $F_{1\text{(lowerBound)}} =  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t(4c - 4cx_0+4az_0)+t^2(-8cy_0+8bz_0)+t^3(4c+4cx_0-4az_0)}{(1+t^2)^2(|b(-1+x_0+t^2(1+x_0))-a(y_0+t(-2+ty_0))|+ |c-cx_0+ct(t+tx_0-2y_0)+(a+2bt-at^2)z_0|)}dt$

   The code for the integrands of the lowerbound after substitution:

   ```
   F1LBIntegrand = -((4*t*(c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t - a*t^2)*z0))/((1 + t^2)^2*(Abs[b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))] + Abs[c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t -a*t^2)*z0])))
   F2LBIntegrand = (2*(b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))))/((1 + t^2)*(Abs[b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))] + Abs[c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t -a*t^2)*z0]))
   F3LBIntegrand = -((2*(-1 + t^2)*(c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t - a*t^2)*z0))/((1 + t^2)^2*(Abs[b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))] + Abs[c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t - a*t^2)*z0])))
   F4LBIntegrand = (4*t*((-b)*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) + a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))))/((1 + t^2)^2*(Abs[b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))] + Abs[c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t -a*t^2)*z0]))
   F5LBIntegrand = -((2*(-1 + t^2)*(b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))))/((1 + t^2)^2*(Abs[b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))] + Abs[c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t - a*t^2)*z0])))
   F6LBIntegrand = (2*(-c + c*x0 - c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) - 2*b*t*z0 + a*(-1 + t^2)*z0))/((1 + t^2)*(Abs[b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0)) - a*(y0 + t*(-2 + t*y0))] + Abs[c - c*x0 + c*t*(t + t*x0 - 2*y0) + (a + 2*b*t -a*t^2)*z0]))
   ```

   2) Following are two indefinite integrals with one of the four cases when removing the abs.

   ```
   F1LB=-4*(((-b)*c*x0 - a*c*t*x0 - c^2*x0^2 + a*c*y0 - b*c*t*y0 - c^2*y0^2 + a^2*t*z0 + b^2*t*z0 + 2*a*c*x0*z0 + 2*b*c*y0*z0 - a^2*z0^2 - b^2*z0^2)/(2*(1 + t^2)*(a^2 + b^2 + 2*b*c*x0 + c^2*x0^2 - 2*a*c*y0 + c^2*y0^2 - 2*a*c*x0*z0 - 2*b*c*y0*z0 + a^2*z0^2 + b^2*z0^2)) + ((a^3*c + a*b^2*c - 2*a*b^2*c*x0^2 - a*c^3*x0^2 - 2*a*b*c^2*x0^3 - 2*a^2*c^2*y0 - 2*b^2*c^2*y0 + 3*a^2*b*c*x0*y0 - b^3*c*x0*y0 - 2*b*c^3*x0*y0 +2*a^2*c^2*x0^2*y0 + b*c^3*x0^3*y0 - a^3*c*y0^2 + a*b^2*c*y0^2 +a*c^3*y0^2 - 2*a*b*c^2*x0*y0^2 - a*c^3*x0^2*y0^2 + 2*a^2*c^2*y0^3 +b*c^3*x0*y0^3 - a*c^3*y0^4 + 2*a^2*b*c*z0 + 2*b^3*c*z0 + a^2*b^2*x0*z0 +b^4*x0*z0 + 2*a^2*c^2*x0*z0 + 2*b^2*c^2*x0*z0 + 4*a^2*b*c*x0^2*z0 -b^2*c^2*x0^3*z0 - a^3*b*y0*z0 - a*b^3*y0*z0 - 4*a^3*c*x0*y0*z0 +4*a*b^2*c*x0*y0*z0 - a*b*c^2*x0^2*y0*z0 - 4*a^2*b*c*y0^2*z0 +2*a^2*c^2*x0*y0^2*z0 - 3*b^2*c^2*x0*y0^2*z0 + 3*a*b*c^2*y0^3*z0 -a^3*c*z0^2 - a*b^2*c*z0^2 - 2*a^3*b*x0*z0^2 - 2*a*b^3*x0*z0^2 +2*a*b^2*c*x0^2*z0^2 + 2*a^4*y0*z0^2 + 2*a^2*b^2*y0*z0^2 a^2*b*c*x0*y0*z0^2 + 3*b^3*c*x0*y0*z0^2 - a^3*c*y0^2*z0^2 - 3*a*b^2*c*y0^2*z0^2 - a^2*b^2*x0*z0^3 - b^4*x0*z0^3 + a^3*b*y0*z0^3 + a*b^3*y0*z0^3)*ArcTan[t])/(2*(a^2 + b^2 + 2*b*c*x0 + c^2*x0^2 - 2*a*c*y0 + c^2*y0^2 - 2*a*c*x0*z0 - 2*b*c*y0*z0 + a^2*z0^2 + b^2*z0^2)^2) + (((-a^3)*c^2 - a*b^2*c^2 - 2*a^3*b*c*x0 - 2*a*b^3*c*x0 - a^3*c^2*x0^2 - a*b^2*c^2*x0^2 + a*c^4*x0^2 + 2*a*b^3*c*x0^3 + 2*a*b^2*c^2*x0^4 - a*c^4*x0^4 + a^4*c*y0 - b^4*c*y0 + 2*a^2*c^3*y0 + 2*b^2*c^3*y0 + 2*b*c^4*x0*y0 - 5*a^2*b^2*c*x0^2*y0 + b^4*c*x0^2*y0 - a^2*c^3*x0^2*y0 - b^2*c^3*x0^2*y0 - 4*a^2*b*c^2*x0^3*y0 - 2*b*c^4*x0^3*y0 - b^2*c^3*x0^4*y0 - a^3*c^2*y0^2 - a*b^2*c^2*y0^2 - a*c^4*y0^2 + 4*a^3*b*c*x0*y0^2 - 2*a*b^3*c*x0*y0^2 + 2*a^3*c^2*x0^2*y0^2 + 2*a*b^2*c^2*x0^2*y0^2 + 2*a*b*c^3*x0^3*y0^2 - a^4*c*y0^3 + a^2*b^2*c*y0^3 - a^2*c^3*y0^3 - b^2*c^3*y0^3 - 4*a^2*b*c^2*x0*y0^3 - 2*b*c^4*x0*y0^3 - a^2*c^3*x0^2*y0^3 - b^2*c^3*x0^2*y0^3 + 2*a^3*c^2*y0^4 + a*c^4*y0^4 + 2*a*b*c^3*x0*y0^4 - a^2*c^3*y0^5 + a^4*b*z0 + 2*a^2*b^3*z0 + b^5*z0 - 2*a^2*b*c^2*z0 - 2*b^3*c^2*z0 + 2*a^4*c*x0*z0 + 2*a^2*b^2*c*x0*z0 - 2*a^2*c^3*x0*z0 - 2*b^2*c^3*x0*z0 - a^2*b^3*x0^2*z0 - b^5*x0^2*z0 + a^2*b*c^2*x0^2*z0 + b^3*c^2*x0^2*z0 - 4*a^2*b^2*c*x0^3*z0 + 4*a^2*c^3*x0^3*z0 + 2*b^2*c^3*x0^3*z0 + b^3*c^2*x0^4*z0 + 2*a^3*b*c*y0*z0 + 2*a*b^3*c*y0*z0 + 2*a^3*b^2*x0*y0*z0 + 2*a*b^4*x0*y0*z0 + 2*a^3*c^2*x0*y0*z0 + 2*a*b^2*c^2*x0*y0*z0 + 8*a^3*b*c*x0^2*y0*z0 - 4*a*b^3*c*x0^2*y0*z0 + 6*a*b*c^3*x0^2*y0*z0 - a^4*b*y0^2*z0 - a^2*b^3*y0^2*z0 + 3*a^2*b*c^2*y0^2*z0 + 3*b^3*c^2*y0^2*z0 - 4*a^4*c*x0*y0^2*z0 + 8*a^2*b^2*c*x0*y0^2*z0 + 6*b^2*c^3*x0*y0^2*z0 - 3*a^2*b*c^2*x0^2*y0^2*z0 + 3*b^3*c^2*x0^2*y0^2*z0 - 4*a^3*b*c*y0^3*z0 - 2*a*b*c^3*y0^3*z0 + 2*a^3*c^2*x0*y0^3*z0 - 6*a*b^2*c^2*x0*y0^3*z0 + 3*a^2*b*c^2*y0^4*z0 - a^5*z0^2 - 2*a^3*b^2*z0^2 - a*b^4*z0^2 + a^3*c^2*z0^2 + a*b^2*c^2*z0^2 - 2*a^3*b*c*x0*z0^2 - 2*a*b^3*c*x0*z0^2 + 2*a^3*b^2*x0^2*z0^2 + 2*a*b^4*x0^2*z0^2 - 6*a^3*c^2*x0^2*z0^2 - 6*a*b^2*c^2*x0^2*z0^2 - 2*a*b^3*c*x0^3*z0^2 - a^4*c*y0*z0^2 - 4*a^2*b^2*c*y0*z0^2 - 3*b^4*c*y0*z0^2 - 4*a^4*b*x0*y0*z0^2 - 4*a^2*b^3*x0*y0*z0^2 - 6*a^2*b*c^2*x0*y0*z0^2 - 6*b^3*c^2*x0*y0*z0^2 + 3*a^2*b^2*c*x0^2*y0*z0^2 - 3*b^4*c*x0^2*y0*z0^2 + 2*a^5*y0^2*z0^2 + 2*a^3*b^2*y0^2*z0^2 + 6*a*b^3*c*x0*y0^2*z0^2 - a^4*c*y0^3*z0^2 - 3*a^2*b^2*c*y0^3*z0^2 + a^4*b*z0^3 + 2*a^2*b^3*z0^3 + b^5*z0^3 + 4*a^4*c*x0*z0^3 + 6*a^2*b^2*c*x0*z0^3 + 2*b^4*c*x0*z0^3 + a^2*b^3*x0^2*z0^3 + b^5*x0^2*z0^3 + 2*a^3*b*c*y0*z0^3 + 2*a*b^3*c*y0*z0^3 - 2*a^3*b^2*x0*y0*z0^3 - 2*a*b^4*x0*y0*z0^3 + a^4*b*y0^2*z0^3 + a^2*b^3*y0^2*z0^3 - a^5*z0^4 - 2*a^3*b^2*z0^4 - a*b^4*z0^4)*ArcTan[(a + b*t + c*t + b*t*x0 + c*t*x0 -c*y0 - a*t*y0 + b*z0 - a*t*z0)/Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2 + c^2 + b^2*x0^2 -c^2*x0^2- 2*a*b*x0*y0 + a^2*y0^2 - c^2*y0^2 + 2*a*c*x0*z0 + 2*b*c*y0*z0 -a^2*z0^2 - b^2*z0^2]])/(2*Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2 + c^2 + b^2*x0^2 - c^2*x0^2 -2*a*b*x0*y0 + a^2*y0^2 - c^2*y0^2 + 2*a*c*x0*z0 + 2*b*c*y0*z0 - a^2*z0^2- b^2*z0^2]*(a^2 + b^2 + 2*b*c*x0 + c^2*x0^2 - 2*a*c*y0 +c^2*y0^2- 2*a*c*x0*z0 - 2*b*c*y0*z0 + a^2*z0^2 + b^2*z0^2)^2) + (((a^2)*b*c - b^3*c - 2*a^2*c^2*x0 - 2*b^2*c^2*x0 - a^2*b*c*x0^2 +b^3*c*x0^2 - b*c^3*x0^2 + 2*b^2*c^2*x0^3 + b*c^3*x0^4 + a^3*c*x0*y0 -3*a*b^2*c*x0*y0 + 2*a*c^3*x0*y0 - 2*a*b*c^2*x0^2*y0 - a*c^3*x0^3*y0 +2*a^2*b*c*y0^2 + b*c^3*y0^2 + 2*b^2*c^2*x0*y0^2 + b*c^3*x0^2*y0^2 -2*a*b*c^2*y0^3 - a*c^3*x0*y0^3 + 2*a^3*c*z0 + 2*a*b^2*c*z0 +a^3*b*x0*z0+a*b^3*x0*z0 - 4*a*b^2*c*x0^2*z0 - 3*a*b*c^2*x0^3*z0 -a^4*y0*z0 - a^2*b^2*y0*z0 - 2*a^2*c^2*y0*z0 - 2*b^2*c^2*y0*z0 +4*a^2*b*c*x0*y0*z0 - 4*b^3*c*x0*y0*z0 + 3*a^2*c^2*x0^2*y0*z0 -2*b^2*c^2*x0^2*y0*z0 + 4*a*b^2*c*y0^2*z0 + a*b*c^2*x0*y0^2*z0 +a^2*c^2*y0^3*z0 + a^2*b*c*z0^2 + b^3*c*z0^2 + 2*a^2*b^2*x0*z0^2 +2*b^4*x0*z0^2 + 3*a^2*b*c*x0^2*z0^2 + b^3*c*x0^2*z0^2 - 2*a^3*b*y0*z0^2-2*a*b^3*y0*z0^2 - 3*a^3*c*x0*y0*z0^2 + a*b^2*c*x0*y0*z0^2 -2*a^2*b*c*y0^2*z0^2 - a^3*b*x0*z0^3 - a*b^3*x0*z0^3 + a^4*y0*z0^3 +a^2*b^2*y0*z0^3)*Log[1 + t^2])/(4*(a^2 + b^2 + 2*b*c*x0 + c^2*x0^2 -2*a*c*y0 + c^2*y0^2 - 2*a*c*x0*z0 - 2*b*c*y0*z0 + a^2*z0^2 +b^2*z0^2)^2)+ ((a^2*b*c + b^3*c + 2*a^2*c^2*x0 + 2*b^2*c^2*x0 +a^2*b*c*x0^2 - b^3*c*x0^2 + b*c^3*x0^2 - 2*b^2*c^2*x0^3 - b*c^3*x0^4 -a^3*c*x0*y0 + 3*a*b^2*c*x0*y0 - 2*a*c^3*x0*y0 + 2*a*b*c^2*x0^2*y0 + a*c^3*x0^3*y0 - 2*a^2*b*c*y0^2 - b*c^3*y0^2 - 2*b^2*c^2*x0*y0^2 -b*c^3*x0^2*y0^2 + 2*a*b*c^2*y0^3 + a*c^3*x0*y0^3 - 2*a^3*c*z0 -2*a*b^2*c*z0 - a^3*b*x0*z0 - a*b^3*x0*z0 + 4*a*b^2*c*x0^2*z0 + 3*a*b*c^2*x0^3*z0 + a^4*y0*z0 + a^2*b^2*y0*z0 + 2*a^2*c^2*y0*z0 +2*b^2*c^2*y0*z0 - 4*a^2*b*c*x0*y0*z0 + 4*b^3*c*x0*y0*z0 -3*a^2*c^2*x0^2*y0*z0 + 2*b^2*c^2*x0^2*y0*z0 - 4*a*b^2*c*y0^2*z0 - a*b*c^2*x0*y0^2*z0 - a^2*c^2*y0^3*z0 - a^2*b*c*z0^2 - b^3*c*z0^2 -2*a^2*b^2*x0*z0^2 - 2*b^4*x0*z0^2 - 3*a^2*b*c*x0^2*z0^2 -b^3*c*x0^2*z0^2 + 2*a^3*b*y0*z0^2 + 2*a*b^3*y0*z0^2 + 3*a^3*c*x0*y0*z0^2 -a*b^2*c*x0*y0*z0^2 + 2*a^2*b*c*y0^2*z0^2 + a^3*b*x0*z0^3 + a*b^3*x0*z0^3- a^4*y0*z0^3 - a^2*b^2*y0*z0^3)*Log[-b + c + 2*a*t + b*t^2 + c*t^2 + b*x0- c*x0 + b*t^2*x0 + c*t^2*x0 - a*y0 - 2*c*t*y0 - a*t^2*y0 + a*z0 + 2*b*t*z0- a*t^2*z0])/(4*(a^2 + b^2 + 2*b*c*x0 + c^2*x0^2 - 2*a*c*y0 +c^2*y0^2 - 2*a*c*x0*z0 - 2*b*c*y0*z0 + a^2*z0^2 + b^2*z0^2)^2))
   F2LB=(-2*(a^2 + b*(b + c*x0) - a*c*y0)*ArcTan[t] + (2*(a^3*y0*z0^2 - b*(c^2*x0*(-1 + x0^2 + y0^2) + b^2*x0*z0^2 + b*c*(-1 + x0^2 -2*x0*y0*z0)) - a^2*(b*x0*z0^2 + c*(-1 + y0^2 + 2*x0*y0*z0)) + a*(c^2*y0*(-1 + x0^2 + y0^2) + b^2*y0*z0^2 + 2*b*c*(x0*y0 + x0^2*z0 - y0^2*z0)))*ArcTan[(a + c*(t + t*x0 - y0) + b*(t + t*x0 + z0) - a*t*(y0 + z0))/Sqrt[(-c^2)*(-1 + x0^2 + y0^2) + 2*b*c*y0*z0 + a*(-2*b*x0*y0 + 2*c*x0*z0) + b^2*(-1 + x0^2 - z0^2) + a^2*(-1 + y0^2 - z0^2)]])/Sqrt[(-c^2)*(-1 + x0^2 + y0^2) + 2*b*c*y0*z0 + a*(-2*b*x0*y0 + 2*c*x0*z0) + b^2*(-1 + x0^2 - z0^2) + a^2*(-1 + y0^2 - z0^2)] + (a*c*x0 - a^2*z0 + b*(c*y0 - b*z0))*Log[1 + t^2] + ((-a)*c*x0 + a^2*z0 + b*((-c)*y0 + b*z0))*Log[c*(1 - x0 + t^2*(1 + x0) - 2*t*y0) + b*(-1 + x0 + t^2*(1 + x0) + 2*t*z0) - a*(-2*t + y0 - z0 + t^2*(y0 + z0))])/(c^2*(x0^2 + y0^2) - 2*a*c*(y0 + x0*z0) + 2*b*c*(x0 - y0*z0) + a^2*(1 + z0^2) + b^2*(1 + z0^2))
   b - 2*a*t - b*t^2 - b*x0 - b*t^2*x0 + a*y0 + a*t^2*y0 > 0 && -c - c*t^2 + c*x0 - c*t^2*x0 + 2*c*t*y0 - a*z0 - 2*b*t*z0 + a*t^2*z0 > 0
   ```

To have an idea how the relationship should look like, I sampled the variables $\alpha,\beta ,x_0,y_0$ and compute the integral numerically.  This is some examples of the relationship from 3 out of 6 functions, where blue dots are the integral of the original functions and orange dots are the lower bound.

[image]

Is there any way to further approximate the functions or the integrals? 
Or is it possible to approximate the relationship of the functions as a polynomial based on some observations of the integrated functions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: We do not see the code, only the pictures. Can you publish the code?

Comment: Could you provide the code for Figure 4? This looks like a TIE fighter.